# How to manipulate and send packets caught with Net::PCAP on windows

Tags: perl, tcp, network-programming, ip

I need to change the tcp/ip headers of packets caught with Net::PCAP. I know this is possible with Net::RawIP, but this doesn't work under windows?

Is there a module for this that works with windows? Is there at least to do this in windows with another programming language that I can call in perl, such as C?

To demonstrate what I want to do, here is the code using Net::RawIP, which does not work under windows because I can't install the module:

```
$n = Net::RawIP->new({
ip  => {
    saddr => 'my.target.lan',
    daddr => 'my.target.lan',
},
   tcp => {
   source => 139,
   dest   => 139,
   psh    => 1,
   syn    => 1,
  data   => $your_data
},
});
$n->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pcap_sendpacket using this per module https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Pcap